# Hashmap containskey junit in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

I have below `class`

```
 public class EmployeeService{
 
   private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;
   private final Map<String, Employee> cache;

   @Autowired
   public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository employeeRepo, Map<String, Employee> cache){
     this.employeeRepo = employeeRepo;
     this.cache = cache;
   }

   public void loadFromDB(){
     //repo call
     cache.put("123", {employee object})
   }
 }
```

I want to write a junit for this where I need to check that value is inserted into cache. I tried below but there is no value in cache.

```
@Mock
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;

@Mock
private Map<String, Employee> cache;

@InjectMocks
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    employeeService = new EmployeeService(employeeRepo, cache);
}

@Test
public void shouldLoadDataFromDBtoCache(){
    when(employeeRepo.findActiveEmployee()).thenReturn(buildDataFromDB());
    EmployeeService.loadFromDB();
    Assertions.assertFalse(cache.isEmpty());
    //Assertions.assertTrue(cache.containsKey("1625"));
    //Assertions.assertTrue(cache.containsKey("1525"));
    //Assertions.assertFalse(cache.containsKey("1425"));
}
```

For `cache.containsKey()` getting `assertion error` when I check size of the cache map is zero.

```
Assertions.assertFalse(cache.isEmpty()); // this is success.
```

How can I test `hashmap containsKey` as above.

Comment: Don't mock your cache, it is just a Map. So just removing the @Mock annotation and instantiating with a HashMap should work.
You probably should only mock the EmployeeRepository

Comment: Also avoid `assertTrue` and `assertFalse` with internal expressions. Normally you'd have something like `assertThat(cache).isNotEmpty()`, which will give you much more helpful debugging in case of a test failure.

Comment: I tried without mocking cache and instantiating with a `HashMap` but then I am getting `NullPointerException` for cache in Service class

Comment: Have a look at my answer and see if that resolves your issue

Comment: Also updated my answer to show `EmployeeService.loadFromDB();` should be called on the instance so should be `employeeService.loadFromDB();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see the minimal change you would need is the following:

```
@Mock
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;

private Map<String, Employee> cache = new HashMap<>();

private EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService(employeeRepo, cache);

@Test
public void shouldLoadDataFromDBtoCache(){
    when(employeeRepo.findActiveEmployee()).thenReturn(buildDataFromDB());
    employeeService.loadFromDB();
    Assertions.assertFalse(cache.isEmpty());
    //Assertions.assertTrue(cache.containsKey("1625"));
    //Assertions.assertTrue(cache.containsKey("1525"));
    //Assertions.assertFalse(cache.containsKey("1425"));
}
```